# Can't find the memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory, ipad, memory-leaks

I've got a fairly simple app that has the following in the view the program is mostly in:

```
int currentPageIndex;
NSArray *images;
NSString *nextImage;    
IBOutlet UIImageView *firstPage;
IBOutlet UIButton *bigButton;
```

In the implementation viewDidLoad, I load the array with a bunch of image file names:

```
images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", etc, nil];
[images retain];
```

Each time the bigButton is tapped, the image changes:

```
- (IBAction)bigButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    currentPageIndex++;

    nextImage = [images objectAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
    firstPage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nextImage];
}
```

Everything works as I want it to, except that I am getting a "Received memory warning. Level=1" in the console with my device plugged in. This warning comes up after every 12 images or so, and eventually it crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I thought this would actually be a good way not to put anything in memory, as there is only one UIImageView on the screen and its image is changed as I need it to be.

It is a very simple app so I'm sure the fix is very simple... any ideas what I might be overlooking?   Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes - firstPage is a UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get a memory warning, the problem must be that the images aren't released. However, in the code you show, you're handling the images correctly. So the problem is most likely in a part of the code you're not showing us.

The only minor problem is see, which has been mentioned before, is that the *currentPageIndex* will eventually point outside of the range of the array. But this will cause a different error.

Comment: Codo, you are awarded the correct answer because there does indeed seem to be nothing wrong with the images. The memory warning is a part of some other code elsewhere.  SORRY for a non-solvable question/post and THANK YOU for your response (and everyone else that responded).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid going over the size of the Array,

currentPageIndex= 0;

for(currentPageIndex in images){

doStuff;

}

**OH!!!!! I THINK** I spotted the your problem. Whenever you use UIImage imageNamed to load images all the images stay in memmory even though release  reference to it. use the other UIImage method:contentOfFile.

One other thing, make sure your images are optimize for iOS. Use .png when posibible.

dibu2z

Comment: Yeah - I have definitely found that [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:  is the way to go rather than imageNamed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume Image is a retained property.
Try to release it at the beginning of your bigButtonTapped.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is bad advice. Just "trying releasing" is a quick way to add even more confusion to a memory management problem.

Comment: By trying I meant he should look for the documentation , and figure out if that's the right thing to do.
Anyway, here it says that image is indeed retained : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
Meaning - he should release it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you've reached the end of the array and you're trying to access past the end of the array.  You could do a

```
currentPageIndex++;

if ( currentPageIndex < [images count]) {
nextImage = [images objectAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
firstPage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nextImage];
}
```

Also could be that the image you listed doesn't exist in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information here to say for sure what your problem is. EXC_BAD_ACCESS generally happens when you try to access an objects that has already been deallocated.

The quickest way to track down the real cause of EXC_BAD_ACCESS is by using the NSZombieEnabled executable argument, and then setting a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw. This will get you a stack trace, and allow you to determine specifically which object you are trying to access.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

[Using Malloc to debug](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/)